# Is this .Net code using Kerberos or NTLM?

Tags: asp.net, .net, active-directory

I have the following code in a system and I am struggling to find out from the MSDN documentation if this method will be using Kerberos or NTLM get the users group list.

```
private static List<SecurityIdentifier> GetUserGroupIds(string user, string groupType, PrincipalContext pc)
{

    using (var identity = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, user))
    {
        if (identity == null)
        {
            return new List<SecurityIdentifier>();
        }

        var userEntry = identity.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

        userEntry.RefreshCache(new[] { groupType });

        return (from byte[] sid in userEntry.Properties[groupType]
                select new SecurityIdentifier(sid, 0)).ToList();
    }

}
```

Any ideas on how I can tell?  I have tried to use PerfMon to capture a trace of the NTLM and Kerberos calls but its difficult to tell as there are other services running on the machine.

Comment: I think the network monitor would be the appropriate tool to capture the authentication traces. Especially because it already has a predefined "authentication traffic" filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `AuthenticationTypes` property of `DirectoryEntry` (in your case, the userEntry object) contains the necessary information:
If the value contains the `AuthenticationTypes.Sealing` flag, i think it is using kerberos.
To cross check:
When using username and password to get a `DirectoryEntry` object using the following code `new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=aaa,DC=bbb,DC=ccc,DC=ddd", "{userName}", "{password}");` the flag mentioned above is set to `AuthenticationTypes.Secure`.